# Getting active img when stacked inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of images that are stacked on each other and I'm trying to manipulate the one in focus (the one currently displayed on top) All the img div tags have an absolute position so they're displayed on top of each other.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="origin" class="ui-test">
  <div class="polaroid ui-test">
      <img src="http://example.com/84655/l/72105d6f46205a948f00f6e59c299930.jpg" >
  </div>
  <div class="polaroid ui-test">
      <img src="http://example.com/77676/l/819e2093be4c61d2e21b1175f9d0f0f9.jpg" >
  </div>
  <div class="polaroid ui-test" style="left: 288.328125px; top: -8px; display: none;">
      <img src="http://example.com/47901/l/79f936ef9847793254bad21e16b2448f.jpg" >
  </div>
  <div class="polaroid ui-test" style="left: 94.328125px; top: 6px; display: none;">
      <img src="http://example.com/49761/l/6d10064d6b189c6934fd264ac295f5f8.jpg" >
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var currentImg= $('.polaroid:focus'); 

currentImg.animate().toggle( "drop");
```

It's not returning what I would expect.  I'm expecting for it to return the second image down (the one currently shown)

Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's controlling the stacking/positioning? I don't see why two are set to `display: none` and two are not. If only one can be seen at a time, three should be hidden. `:focus` refers to where the user has focus (form fields, anchors) and doesn't apply.

Comment: They all have an absolute position so they appear to be stacked on top of each other

Comment: Are they all covering each other completely? Or staggered? You need to define what "in focus" means - if it's what's on top then you need to find whichever has the top-most `z-index`, if it's what's currently visible, you can use `:visible` assuming all others are hidden.

Comment: they are all covering each other completely...how would I determine the z-index for the one visisble

Comment: There are few ways to find which has the highest z-index but before I provide an example can you confirm it's using z-index to show them? Seems awfully inefficient when the code should just be hiding the other images not visible.

Comment: there is no z-index.  They are shown with the bottom most visible div container on top.  In my example above it would be: http://example.com/77676/l/819e2093be4c61d2e21b1175f9d0f0f9.jpg

Comment: So is it hiding the other three images via styles?

Comment: @BotskoNet that is correct

Comment: If they're truly hidden, then @Will has your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var currentImg = $('.polaroid:visible');
```

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ for more.

Comment: hmm...that seems to remove the entire stack of images.  I'm trying to remove only the top one in focus.

Comment: If you're using z-index instead of visibility or display, this will indeed get them all.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this to find the top visible div:

```
    var currentImg;
    $('.polaroid').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            currentImg = this;
        }
    });

    console.log(currentImg);
```